# Printing expressions of variables in Theano

Tags: python, debugging, theano

If I want to print some variable for debugging in theano, it is easy, just write
 `x2 = printing.Print('x is: ')(x)`, and then use `x2` instead of `x` in the following computations.
But what if I want to print some expression of `x`, for example `x+y`. How can I do it?
If I write `z = printing.Print('x+y is: ')(x+y)` then I will need to insert `z` into the computation graph later, what is the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a print operation must be reachable (via some path in the computation graph) from an output of the Theano function. If you want to print an expression that is not used then a simple solution is to just include the result of that expression in the outputs of the Theano function.

Suppose you are interested in `x*y` but would like to print `x+y`, then

```
x = theano.tensor.scalar()
y = theano.tensor.scalar()
z = printing.Print('x+y is: ')(x+y)
f1 = theano.function([x, y], [x * y]
f2 = theano.function([x, y], [z]
f3 = theano.function([x, y], [x * y, z]
```

f1 will fail to print `x+y` because z is not reachable from an output of the function; f2 will print `x+y` but will not compute `x*y`; f3 will do both.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there may be some way to insert it into the graph made specifically for debugging, so that I don't have to handle that extra value that now appears in the output of the function. But apparently there is no such thing.

Comment: My main problem is that if the function is highly nested inside many other functions, then I will have to make a lot of modifications to all those other functions in order to propagate this new z variable till the end.

Comment: I assume this is for debugging? The page on debugging Theano programs in the documentation might be useful. In particuilar, the section on stepping through Theano functions and inspecting inputs/outputs (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-step-through-a-compiled-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty hack, but I've resorted to things like:

```
x = 1e-11 * Print("mean of x")(x.mean()) + x
```

If you make it `0 * Print(...)` then it gets optimised away.